# Pebble: JavaScript Send Data from Server to Pebble

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I am trying to parse data from an API to my pebble but I don't know how to proceed. Was browsing through pebble development and they say JavaScript is a good gateway and I can make HTTP requests but I don't know JS.

What do I need in my .c file and what do I need in my .JS file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [quotes](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/blob/master/pebblekit-js/quotes/) example is really simple and probably very close to what you want to do. I would start there:

- On the [JavaScript side](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/blob/master/pebblekit-js/quotes/src/js/pebble-js-app.js), you will make your request to the webservice, check the response is ok and then just send the elements that you are interested in to the Pebble (with `Pebble.sendAppMessage()`.
- [On the Pebble side](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/blob/master/pebblekit-js/quotes/src/quotes.c), you initialize AppMessage in your [`init()`](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/blob/master/pebblekit-js/quotes/src/quotes.c#L91) function and then declare a handler that will be called every time a message is received ([`in_received_handler`](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/blob/master/pebblekit-js/quotes/src/quotes.c#L69) in this example). That handler will update the information on the screen.